Panning and zooming map while using Leaflet Draw
The default behaviour of Leaflet Draw is to expect a single click to create vertices for lines and polygons. I find this impractical, especially for mobile devices. For example when I try to draw a polygon on mobile phone and start dragging/zooming the map while drawing, the touch input is automatically registered as a vertex input. Is there a way to modify Leaflet Draw to prevent this?
I am using Leaflet.draw 1.0.4 with leaflet 1.7.1
Code adding the Draw Control to the map:
    // Leaflet Draw Control 

var customIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'marker.png',
        iconSize: [30, 30],
        iconAnchor: [15, 25],
        popupAnchor: [-3, -76] });
    
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    },
    draw: {
        polygon: {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#94e50e',
                opacity: 1
            },
            showArea: true,
            metric: true
        },
        polyline: {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#94e50e',
                opacity: 1
            },
            showLength: true,
            metric: true
        },
        rectangle: false,
        circle: false,
        marker: {
            icon: customIcon
        },
        circlemarker: false
    } }); map.addControl(drawControl);


Taken from leaflet.draw issue #935
L.Draw.Polyline.prototype._onTouch = L.Util.falseFn;

Panning or Zooming while drawing Polylines and Polygons does not create new vertices. Tested on Mobile and Desktop.
